# How to pass properties from application.properties to logback config file

Tags: spring-boot, logback, sentry

Overview:

I am using Sentry appender in my logback.xml file and I want to pass plenty of tags as parameters from application.properties file to logback config file.

**logback.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>

    <appender name="SENTRY" class="com.getsentry.raven.logback.SentryAppender">
        <dsn>
            https://e0a61232c92f42ffa34c22914d676a8e:e64f7edc60de490eb004556d2b3fce45@sentry.io/112817
        </dsn>
        <springProfile name="dev">
            <tags>env:dev,app:${app.name},platform:aws</tags>
        </springProfile>
        <springProfile name="stage">
            <tags>env:dev</tags>
        </springProfile>
        <springProfile name="test">
            <tags>env:test</tags>
        </springProfile>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="SENTRY"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

**application.properties:**

```
security.ignored=/**

logging.level.root = DEBUG

spring.profiles.active=dev
app.name=retailServices
```

**Note:** 
the spring.profiles.active property in application.properties is mapped to springProfile tag in logback config file.

---

**But the issue** is the fact that the "app.name" property cannot be found in logback.xml file. If I use this property as system properties it works but I want to pass it to config file from application.properties.

So any solution, feedback and idea would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In `logback.xml` include:

```
<property resource="application.properties" />
```

And then you can refer properties in a standard way, for example `${app.name}`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I forgot this include.

Comment: well this was help full - i have an additional requirement that i want to pass - application.properties path from my command line args , is there a way to do that , i tried digging it out - but did not get anything

Answer (score 8):

I found that Spring has support of next tag `<springProperty/>` described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) . It means that you can easily add variable from property files even this variable value spring resolves from environment/system variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it now directly via a logback context, or via a third party encoder.

```
  LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
  context.putProperty("global", "value");
```

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/pull/794

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this is still a valid question.

Here is my solution, let's say you have a different spring profile and base on it want to change the configuration like `log pattern, path of log file create, size of log file ...etc.`

It can do it in like below,

let's say, We have two profile called `dev` and `prod` those config files look like below,

`application-dev.properties`

```
spring.application.name=Admin Module
logback.log.pattern=%-5level [%thread] %logger{36} : %X{correlationId} : %m%n
logback.app.log.root=C:\logs\adminModule\
logback.max.file.size=50MB
logback.max.file.history=2
```

`application-prod.properties`

```
spring.application.name=Admin Module
logback.log.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} : ${spring.application.name} : %X{correlationId} : %m%n
logback.app.log.root=\logs\adminModule\
logback.max.file.size=50MB
logback.max.file.history=30
```

`application.properties`

```
# (active profile can get dynamically)
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

This is my `logback.xml` file

```
<configuration>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <!--    get active profile-->
    <springProperty scope="context" name="profile" source="spring.profiles.active"/>
    <!--    get properties from active profile-->
    <property resource="application-${profile}.properties" />
    <property name="LOG_PATTERN" value="${logback.log.pattern}"/>
    <property name="APP_LOG_ROOT" value="${logback.app.log.root}"/>
    <property name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="${logback.max.file.size}"/>
    <property name="MAX_FILE_HISTORY" value="${logback.max.file.history}"/>

    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="infoLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${APP_LOG_ROOT}/info.log</file>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
            <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>ACCEPT</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${APP_LOG_ROOT}/info.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}-%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>${MAX_FILE_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>${MAX_FILE_HISTORY}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="infoLog"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This solution will reduce multiple `logback.xml` files maintain over head.

Comment: Looks like a nice answer but it isn't working....