# Controlling logback environment dependent properties in external application properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

In my `spring-boot` application I use `logback` for logging.  The application uses external `application.properties` file for setting environment specific application properties and starts with option: `-spring.config.location=path/to/file`. I would like logback configuration to read properties from there as well so that all environment properties are managed in one place.

I tried the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497947/how-to-pass-properties-from-application-properties-to-logback-config-file), but since the properties file is not on the classpath, I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.PropertyAction - Could not find resource [application.properties]
```

Is there something I am missing?

UPDATE:

Adding this configuration works:

```
   <property file="path/to/file" />
```

But I would like to avoid hardcoding the file path.

Answer (score 4):

add system environment variable, so logback falls back to this location for configuration file

```
logback.configurationFile=path/to/config.xml
```

Comment: May be it was not clear from my question, but I'd like to have one logback configuration file with a couple of values which differ between environments.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Spring you can use Spring extensions for Logback: [logback-ext-spring](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/wiki/Spring)

What this library does is basically gives you possibility to delegate the actual logging to spring managed objects giving you access to the spring context. You can create and configure appenders within the Spring configuration where you will have access to the `Environment` variables and therefore also to `application.properties`.

You can find more info on the GitHub page but here is an example configuration, based on the example provided in the link, where the pattern for the console appender is retrieved from the environment property `"consolePattern"`:

*logback.xml*:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.DelegatingLogbackAppender"/>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

*LogbackConfig.java*:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder;
import ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender;
import ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.ApplicationContextHolder;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class LogbackConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean 
    public static ApplicationContextHolder applicationContextHolder() {
        return new ApplicationContextHolder();
    }

    @Bean 
    public static LoggerContext loggerContext() {
        return (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    }

    @Bean (initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public static PatternLayoutEncoder encoder (LoggerContext ctx) {
        PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        encoder.setContext(ctx);
        encoder.setPattern(environment.getProperty("consolePattern");
        return encoder;
    }

    @Bean (initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public static ConsoleAppender consoleAppender (LoggerContext ctx, PatternLayoutEncoder encoder) {
        ConsoleAppender appender = new ConsoleAppender();
        appender.setContext(ctx);
        appender.setEncoder(encoder);
        return appender;
    }
}
```

> **Important** 
>   Please note that the spring bean name must match the name of the appender in the `logback.xml`, in the example `"consoleAppender"`. Also don't forget to specify the `initMethod` and `destroyMethod`.

Hope this helps you to find the way not to hardcode the path.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using spring boot to run your app you can do:

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property file="${configuration.file.path}" />
    .......
</configuration>
```

You can change "configuration.file.path", but you have to change that name after when you run your app.

You can use the properties defined on the property file like this:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - ${property.defined.in.property.file} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<root level="${level.defined.in.property.file}">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

And add the param to the VM when you execute your app

```
-Dlogging.config=/some/path/logback.xml -Dconfiguration.file.path=/other/path/application.properties
```

logging.config is a spring-boot configuration, so you must to keep that name. You can change that file in every execution without change a configuration in your app.

if you execute manually your app by command line, should be like:

```
java -Dlogging.config=/some/path/logback.xml -Dconfiguration.file.path=/other/path/application.properties -jar app-1.0.0.jar .....
```

Doing this, all the logging configuration is dynamic, and you're giving it when you run the app. You can have different instances with different configurations

Answer (score 1):

We don't use `spring-boot` but maybe this approach might be helpful:

We created this `LogbackConfigurator`. This class is executed on application startup by listening to the ContextRefreshedEvent:

```
public class LogbackConfigurator implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>
{
    // configure your configuration file here
    private static final String         LOGBACK_CONFIGURATION   = "some/where/application.properties";


    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event)
    {
        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        try
        {
            // creating JoranConfigurator
            JoranConfigurator joranConfigurator = new JoranConfigurator();

            // setting logger context for JoranConfiguratior
            joranConfigurator.setContext(loggerContext);

            // resetting context, override default configuration
            loggerContext.reset(); 

            // configuring Logback with resource
            joranConfigurator.doConfigure(new Resource(LOGBACK_CONFIGURATION).getInputStream());
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // exception handling
        }
    }
}
```

To have the bean executed, we added this line in our Java configuration:

```
@Bean
public LogbackTestConfigurator logbackConfigurator()
{
    return new LogbackTestConfigurator();
}
```